# Fatwire Content getting only first time after publishing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, fatwire

```
@Autowired
private xxx abc;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Inside the do Servlet!!!");
    String pageId = request.getParameter("pageId");
    abc.resetSessionVariables();
    FatwireContent content=new FatwireContent();
    abc.setFatwireContent(content);

    System.out.println(abc.retrieveFatWireContent(
                    "xxxx", "xxxx"));

    abc.getFatwireContent().setImportantinformation(
            abc.retrieveFatWireContent(
                    "xxxx", "xxxx"));
    abc.getFatwireContent().setMainlegalfootnote(
            abc.retrieveFatWireContent(
                    "xxxx", "xxxx"));
    abc.getFatwireContent().setMethodology(
            abc.retrieveFatWireContent(
                    "RetirementAdvisorTool", "Methodology"));
    abc.getFatwireContent().setThingstoImproveOutcome(abc.retrieveFatWireContent(
                    "xxxx", "xxxx"));




    if (pageId != null && "Step1".equals(pageId))
        response.sendRedirect("xxxx.faces");
    else
        response.sendRedirect("xxxx.faces");
}
```

The above code is populating fatwire content only first time after publising. All other times, I can see that fatwire content getting printed, but nothing comes in page. The fatwire content is retrieving plain htmls. Is there something to do with jsp compliation life cycle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logging the invoked managed bean action in a PhaseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788454/logging-the-invoked-managed-bean-action-in-a-phaselistener)

Added the method in Phase Listener and now its working fine.