# Logging the invoked managed bean actionListener in a PhaseListener

Tags: jsf-2, phaselistener

I need to log actions fired from managed Bean.This link , [Logging the invoked managed bean action in a PhaseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788454/logging-the-invoked-managed-bean-action-in-a-phaselistener) helps me solve the problem related to actions. But, when I use `actionListener` , I have a `NullPointerException`

```
@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();

    if (context.isPostback()) {
        UICommand component = findInvokedCommandComponent(context);

        if (component != null) {
            String methodExpression = component.getActionExpression().getExpressionString(); 
            // It'll contain #{bean.action}.
        }
    }
}

private UICommand findInvokedCommandComponent(FacesContext context) {
    UIViewRoot view = context.getViewRoot();
    Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    if (context.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
        return (UICommand) view.findComponent(params.get("javax.faces.source"));
    } else {
        for (String clientId : params.keySet()) {
            UIComponent component = view.findComponent(clientId);

            if (component instanceof UICommand) {
                return (UICommand) component;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

THe `NullPointerException` occurs with line

```
String methodExpression = component.getActionExpression().getExpressionString();
```

How can I get the name of the `actionListener` method ?
I tried

```
private UICommand findInvokedCommandComponent(FacesContext context) {
        UIViewRoot view = context.getViewRoot();
        Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        if (context.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
            UIComponent component = view.findComponent(params.get("javax.faces.source"));
            if (component instanceof UICommand) {
//                component.get
              UICommand comp=  (UICommand) component;
                ActionListener[] actionListeners=  comp.getActionListeners();
                System.out.println("Taille des Listeners : "+actionListeners.length);
               ActionListener method;
                method = actionListeners[0];
                String toString = method.toString();
                System.out.println("ActionListener : "+toString);
                return (UICommand) component;
            }
        } else {
            for (String clientId : params.keySet()) {
                UIComponent component = view.findComponent(clientId);

                if (component instanceof UICommand) {
                    return (UICommand) component;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
System.out.println("ActionListener : "+toString); returns ActionListener : `javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener@16a779b` . What I would like to have is  `#{bean.action}` .Maybe I did it the wrong way
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the good way, but you need to get the `MethodExpressionActionListener` which implements the `ActionListener`. Using it, you still can't get the `MethodExpression` out of the box, probably the only way is to get it by reflection (not the best thing...).

That said, you can modify your code like this :

```
if (component != null) {
    String methodExpression = "";

    if(component.getActionExpression() != null)
    {
        methodExpression = component.getActionExpression().getExpressionString(); 
    }
    else if(component.getActionListeners().length > 0)
    {
        methodExpression = getActionListener((MethodExpressionActionListener)component.getActionListeners()[0]).getExpressionString();
    }

    System.out.println("Method Expression : " + methodExpression);
}
```

And you will need this method to actually get required information out of the `MethodExpressionActionListener` :

```
private MethodExpression getActionListener(MethodExpressionActionListener listener)
{
    MethodExpression expression = null;
    Field field;

    try
    {
        field = listener.getClass().getDeclaredField("methodExpressionZeroArg");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        expression = (MethodExpression)field.get(listener);

        if(expression == null)
        {
            field = listener.getClass().getDeclaredField("methodExpressionOneArg");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            expression = (MethodExpression)field.get(listener);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return expression;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help and your patience :) Solved with your help